# Unsatisfied Dependency of RestTemplete component when unsing @ComponentScan

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project that I use as a library (dependency of other SpringBoot Application). In this library, I have a REST Client component that access some external Web Service.

My problem happens in Unit Tests. Any Unit Tests don't inject a RestTemplate component when I use a manual @ComponentScan in application. If I use a automatic Component Scan (Commenting the @ComponentScan annotation) it works fine, so the test pass.

I need use a manual @ComponentScan because my library has a dependency to another library too, that have other Spring's components.

I made a simplified example that I need (not my real application, but as I said, I simplified to ilustrate the problem):

**DemorestApplication.java:**

```java
package br.org.otojunior.demo;

// ... imports

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("br.org.otojunior.demo")
public class DemorestApplication { }
```

**DemoRestClient.java**:

```java
package br.org.otojunior.demo;

// ... imports

@Component
public class DemoRestClient {
    private String endpoint = "https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate template;

    public ResponseEntity<DemoRestResponse> query() {
        return template.getForEntity(endpoint, DemoRestResponse.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

**DemoRestResponse.java:**

```java
public class DemoRestResponse {
    private String type;
    public String getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(String type) { this.type = type; }
}
```

And my test class is just this:

**DemoTest.java**:

```java
package br.org.otojunior.demo;

// ... imports

@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DemoTest {
    @Test
    public void test() { }
}
```

When I run this test class, happens a error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoRestClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'template';  
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

As we see, the Spring is searching for the **RestTemplateBuilder** producer.

When I comment the @ComponentScan, it's works. Did I forget any package in @ComponentScan to RestTemplateBuilder works? (I already put the RestTemplateBuilder package in @ComponentScan, but didn't work).

I need to work in this example, because this example is a simplified copy of my real library.

The source code is in: [GitHub DemoRest](https://github.com/otojunior/demorest)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into `@SpringBootApplication` and read source code, you will see that `@SpringBootApplication` is already annotated with `@ComponentScan` so annotationg class that is already annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` with `@ComponentScan` is not recommended . Your problem is that your `@ComponentScan` takes precedence over `@ComponentScan` inside `@SpringBootApplication` and in your `@ComponentScan` you haven't excluded `TypeExcludeFilter`.

This will work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "br.org.otojunior.demo",
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.CUSTOM,
                classes = {TypeExcludeFilter.class}
        )}
)
public class DemorestApplication {

}
```

But, as I already said, you really dont need that `@ComponentScan` at all, `@SpringBootApplication` is enough.

Comment: In my case, the @ComponentScan is necessary because I have in my pom.xml, a dependency to other JAR that have others components. So, the Spring context doesn't watching for components in transitive dependencies